# comparing two img src

Tags: jquery, html

Okay so I have this function that gets the img src for every img with a class of visible:

```
$('.visible').each(function() {
        var img = ($(this).attr('src'));
          alert(img);
            });
```

now I need to compare the first two img src to see if they are the same i tried this:

```
   $('.visible').each(function() {
         var firstImg = ($(this).eq(0).attr('src'));
         var secondImg = ($(this).eq(1).attr('src'));

if(firstImg == secondImg){
alert('match');
}else{
alert('not a match'); 
}

            });
```

this is clearly wrong so how could i go about this?

Comment: Compare `$('.visible:eq(0)')` and `$('.visible:eq(1)')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the `each` handler `this` refers to a single image element, so `$(this).eq(1).attr('src')` will always return `undefined`

what you need is

```
var $imgs = $('.visible');

var firstImg = $imgs.eq(0).attr('src');
var secondImg = $imgs.eq(1).attr('src');

if(firstImg == secondImg){
    alert('match');
}else{
    alert('not a match'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks perfect i cant acecpt your answer yet but i will i soon as i can

Answer (score 3):

See http://jsfiddle.net/j5bsU/

HTML

```
<img class="visible" src="fake.png" />
<img class="visible" src="anotherfake.png" />
<img src="noclassimg.png" />
<img class="visible" src="lastimg.png" />
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var imgs = $('.visible');
    var firstSrc = imgs[0].src;
    var secondSrc = imgs[1].src;
    alert(firstSrc == secondSrc);
});
```